# JNI: characters are missing when try to set the char array value into jstring

Tags: java, c, char, java-native-interface

I have a char array in my c code. I am trying to set the char array value into jstring for returning it to java. Some times Some character are missing at the end. Is there any solution for getting the same string as output.
My code Below:

```
char myvalue[10000] = " { in the same way that Java code uses these objects. A native method can create Java objects and then inspect and use these objects to perform its tasks. A native method can also inspect and use objects created by Java application code.} ";
jstring str = (*env)->NewStringUTFChars(env, myvalue);
```

When i try to print the same jstring value, some characters are missing at the end of the string. How i can i resolve this?.

Comment: Does compiler throw any warnings?

Comment: No. It doesnt throw any warnings. When i try to print the value in c side i am able to see all the characters. After putting it in jstring only some characters are missing in last.

Comment: What is `NewStringUTFChars`? Did you mean `NewStringUTF`? Also, what does _"Some times Some character are missing"_ mean exactly? That is, under which circumstances are characters missing, and _which_ characters are missing (e.g. are they all ASCII-encodable)?.

Comment: As a side note, it seems really wasteful to allocate space for 10,000 characters if you know that the string will be much shorter than that. Just leave out the size (i.e. `char myvalue[] = "blah blah";`) and the compiler will figure it out for you. If you're going to overwrite the contents of the string later with something that you don't know the length of at compile-time: allocate the memory dynamically once you know the length.

Comment: Yes. I mean the `NewStringUTF` only. I am trying to return this string to java. I am using a for loop for return the same string multiple time to java. First time it is retrieved correctly in java side. next time the last 3 characters are missing from the actual string.

Comment: Now you are changing the situation described in your question. Please add the loop and the relevant Java side.